# Zend Helper design usage example

Tags: php, zend-framework, helper

I have a view that loops over a database table returning dogs information.

Here's the controller:

```
public function listAction()
{
  $dogDao = new DogDao();
  $this->view->infoDog = $dogDao->retrieveDogInfo();
}
```

On the view I can retrieve dog information like this:

```
<?php for($i = 0; $i < 30; $i++){ ?>
if(isset($this->infoDog[$i])){
   $dog = $this->infoDog[$i];
```

This works fine.

I now need to add additional dog specific information but that dog information, is not an information that I can get from the Dog General Info table, it requires some joins, and the retrieval of a number at the end.

```
public function retrieveVerySpecificInformation($dogId) {

return $numberSpecificForThatDog

};
```

I (believe) I need a helper that does those calculations and my question is:

I should call this helper on the view where the *for* resides yes? 
But how can I connect those informations in a way that I get for given dog A, both: 
 The general dog information AND that numberSpecific for that particular dog A ?

I mean, how can we properly integrate the helper here?

Can I have some help please?

Thanks in advance,
MEM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may call view helper should like this

```
<?php echo $this->displayDog('A', 'black'); ?>
```

And your view helper should be like

```
class Zend_View_Helper_Dog
{
    public function displayDog($type, $color)
    {
         $dog = new Model_DbTable_Dog();
         return $dog->getDog($type, $color);
    }
}
```

It's **OK** call view helpers from a loop for couple of DB operations, BUT as you are making custom db query for each dog (*30 queries are NOT RECOMMENDED*)

**Recommendation**

You should fetch all info your need with in your controller and pass it to your views, which later can be costumed using any view helper.

```
public function listAction()
{
    this->view->infoAllDog = $dogDao->retrieveAllDogs(); 
    // including joined info + all dogs you may need in your view
```

Comment: I do agree with your recommendation. So, retrieveAllDogs() will have ALL the information returned? The question is: How can I join data from two different queries and each one with a lot of joins, on a single method? Perhaps I should use two methods, and one to put them together? - Can you please upgrade your recommendation to accommodate a similar situation? Thanks a lot in advance.